# Excel - if fields match output ID

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match

Hoping someone can help me write a formula. I have  table one where a certain title/string is listed multiple times. I also have  table two where i have 2 columns, one with ID the other with same titles. I need to be able to assign IDs in table one from table 2 if they match
[image]

Comment: See [Why Not Images of Code and Sample Data](http://tinyurl.com/kdxb7le) and [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). While you are editing your question, be sure to include a little original effort (working or not). You might also want to go watch the video at [VLOOKUP function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/vlookup-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65).

Comment: =VLOOKUP($A1,$B:$C, 2, FALSE)

Comment: thanks for the help!, it was simple after that! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the MATCH function. This will return the index of the matching cell. To get a True/False value, use the ISERROR method. Like so:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A1,B:B, 0)), "False", "True")
```

Where:
- B is the column you want to match against
- A1 is the cell you want to check